# Python web scraping on Morningstar.com through Selenium + XPath

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data related to mutual funds and ETFs on Morningstar.com using the Selenium library, but the following code doesn't work:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
link = "https://www.morningstar.com/etfs/bats/maga/quote.html"
driver.get(link)

TNA = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="gr_table_colm2b"]//span[@id="NAV"]')
print(TNA)
currency = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="gr_text3" and @id="navCurrency"]')
print(currency)

driver.close()
```

What is wrong with it?
I have already checked that Selenium actually opens Chrome by remote and that XPath finds the right pattern in the HTML code.

Comment: No error message, it just returns two empty lists

Answer (score 0):

You're having issues because of iFrames (essentially a webpage in a webapage). To access items in an iFrame, you need to switch to it first.

````
``` 
Define path of iFrame desired. I used a @src contains 
since there are multiple iFrames on the page.
``` 
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'.com/quote')]")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe);

# I added the text part since I figured that was what you ultimately wanted.
TNA = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="gr_table_colm2b"]//span[@id="NAV"]')[0].text
print(TNA)
currency = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="gr_text3" and @id="navCurrency"]')[0].text
print(currency)

27.79  
USD
````

Say you want to switch back to original page, use the following code.

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help W Stokvis, but unfortunately your code does not work on my PC. This is the error message I see: 
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)

Comment: Could be an issue with your chromedriver and you may need to update it. You can find some answers here: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/2631

Comment: Thanks a million! The issue was indeed my chromedriver old version, now it works fine